# ASP.NET MVC 4 Website cannot download JavaScripts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, iis-7.5

I have a correct working ASP.NET MVC 4 (.NET Framework 4.5.6 ) website locally. It works fine under VS 2015 and IIS 7 of Windows 7.

When I deploy the same folder to MS WIn Server 2008 R2 it does not work properly and I am facing lots of errors. Please, check the log.

Any clue how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it using following steps

1. Re-registration  .NET Framework 4 using menu RUN

> %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
>
> %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

2. Install "Recommened configuration IIS 7.0" using MS Web Platform tool

[image]

3. Adding this code to `modules` section of **web.config**

> ```
>  <system.webServer>
>     <modules  runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
>        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
>       <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
>     </modules>
> ```